Japanese font in table overlaps with adjacent column when compiled with XeLaTeX in Overleaf
I'm working on a LaTeX document in Overleaf where I have a table containing text in multiple languages, including Japanese. I'm using XeLaTeX as the compiler. However, when I compile the document, the Japanese text in the table overlaps with the adjacent column.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{chinese, spanish, arabic, portuguese, french, japanese, tamil, german, hindi, bengali, russian}

\newfontfamily\chinesefont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
\newfontfamily\spanishfont{Liberation Serif}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\portuguesefont{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily\frenchfont{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily\japanesefont{Noto Sans CJK JP}
\newfontfamily\tamilfont{Noto Sans Tamil}
\newfontfamily\germanfont{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontfamily\hindifont{Noto Sans Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Noto Sans Bengali}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{PT Sans}
\newfontfamily\ipafont{Charis SIL}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Examples of Transliteration from different languages to UniGlyph:}
    \label{tab:transliteration}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXXX}
        \toprule
        Language & Script in native language & English equivalent & IPA & Temp \\
        \midrule
        English & The sun is shining brightly today & The sun is shining brightly today & {\ipafont ðə sʌn ɪz ˈʃaɪnɪŋ ˈbraɪtˡli təˈdeɪ} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Mandarin Chinese & {\chinesefont 今天太阳很亮} & Jīntiān tàiyáng yǎrqdiào zhàoyàozhe & {\ipafont jɪnˈtʰien tai̯ˈjaŋ jǎːrqdiàu ʈʂao̯jao̯ʈʂɤ} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Spanish & {\spanishfont Hoy el sol brilla intensamente hoy} & Hoy el sol brilla intensamente hoy & {\ipafont oi el ˈsol ˈbrilla inˈtensaˈmente oi} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Arabic & \textarabic{االيوم الشمس تشرق الزاهية} & Al-yom ash-shams tashraqo az-zāhiyah & {\ipafont alˈjoːm ʔaʃˈʃams taʃraqʊ ʔazˈzaːhijah} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Portuguese & {\portuguesefont Hoje o sol está brilhando intensamente hoje} & Hoje o sol está brilhando intensamente hoje & {\ipafont ˈoʒi o ˈsɔw ˈesta brilˈjandu inˈtẽˈsamente ˈoʒi} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        French & {\frenchfont Aujourd'hui, le soleil brille intensément aujourd'hui} & Aujourd'hui, le soleil brille intensément aujourd'hui & {\ipafont oʒuʁˈdui lə soˈlɛj bril intensəmɑ̃ oʒuʁˈdui} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Japanese  & {\japanesefont 今日、太陽は今日はとても明るく輝いています} & Kyōjitsu, taiyō wa kyō wa totemo akiraka ni hikatte imasu & {\ipafont kʲoːdzit͡su taijoː wa kʲoː wa totemo akaraka ni hikatte imasu} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Tamil & {\tamilfont இன்று சூரியன் மிகவும் பிரகாசமாக பிரகாசிக்கிறது} & Indru sūriyan mikavum pirakāśamakāga pirakāśikkiradu & {\ipafont indu suːrijan mikavum piɾakaːsamaːgaka piɾakaːsikkiɾadu} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        German & {\germanfont Heute scheint die Sonne heute sehr hell} & Heute scheint die Sonne heute sehr hell & {\ipafont ˈhɔʏtə ˈʃaɪnt diː ˈzɔnə ˈhɔʏtə zeːr ˈhɛl} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Hindi & {\hindifont आज सूर्य बहुत चमक रहा है आज} & Aaj sūrya bahut chamak rahā hai aaj & {\ipafont aːdz suːrya bahut ˈt͡ʃəmək ˈraɦa hɛː aːdz} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Bengali  & {\bengalifont আজ সূর্য খুব ঝলমলে আছে আজ} & Aaj shurjo khub jholungmole ache aaj & {\ipafont aːdz ʃurjo khub ˈd͡ʒʱolomole at͡ʃe aaj} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Russian & {\russianfont Сегодня солнце ярко светит сегодня} & Segodnya solntse yarko svetit segodnya & {\ipafont sʲɪˈvodnʲə ˈsolnt͡sə ˈjarko ˈsʲvʲetit sʲɪˈvodnʲə} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}

I've tried different Japanese fonts like Noto Serif CJK JP, but the issue persists. The Japanese text spills over into the adjacent column instead of staying within its designated cell.
How can I ensure that the Japanese text in my table is properly aligned and does not overlap with the adjacent column when compiled with XeLaTeX in Overleaf?

you are just selecting the fonts not switching languages so you are not getting any language specific linebreaking all text is being treated as US English

@DavidCarlisle can you correct my code please

One issue with the Japanese is that in-between the glyphs there are non-breaking joinerspaces, so even if you set the languages it will still give you problems. Also are the Cyrillic letters meant to be in the cell with the Chinese? ярко地照耀着. Personally  I would use LuaLaTeX with fallback and just adjust breaks in the 2-3 cells that may need adjustment. Much cleaner.

@yannisl please assist correcting LaTeX code

@yannisl you can remove the Cyrillic letters in Chinese cell

For the first issue, use \textspanish{} rather than {\spanishfont } for example. The same as you do for Arabic already. For the second, switch the compiler to LuaTeX. I'm not sure what @yannisl means by 'with fallback', but the idea is to manually add line breaks in the remaining cases which cause problems.

@cfr  Please see my example, using fallback fonts and their limitations.

Out of curiosity what is Uniglyph and what are the items listed under Temp?

@yannisl I am working on it, surely i will let you know

@yannisl because of you i had added few more old languages but can't able to render it! Here is the link for that thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/721081/creating-a-multi-page-auto-scaling-table-with-repeating-headers-in-latex-for-mu

Note that this may not be the right way to add line breaks in Japanese and it certainly doesn't use the correct places to insert such breaks. The Tamil and Japanese still produce bad boxes, but there's not much point in fiddling when I had to change the page layout to make the full text fit at all. I assume your real document also uses a non-default layout but, of course, I don't know the details.
I compiled with XeTeX, but LuaTeX may give better results. babel may also give better results than polyglossia - for some languages, it offers better support. Most notably, I'm told this is true for RTL languages. However, other may do better with polyglossia.
Mostly, this just demonstrates how to switch languages rather than simply changing fonts.
I've also used \raggedright for the columns because justification is clearly a lost cause in this kind of case.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{chinese, spanish, arabic, portuguese, french, japanese, tamil, german, hindi, bengali, russian}

\newfontfamily\chinesefont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
\newfontfamily\spanishfont{Liberation Serif}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\portuguesefont{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily\frenchfont{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily\japanesefont{Noto Sans CJK JP}
\newfontfamily\tamilfont{Noto Sans Tamil}
\newfontfamily\germanfont{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontfamily\hindifont{Noto Sans Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Noto Sans Bengali}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{PT Sans}
\newfontfamily\ipafont{Charis SIL}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Examples of Transliteration from different languages to UniGlyph:}
    \label{tab:transliteration}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{RRRRR}
        \toprule
        Language & Script in native language & English equivalent & IPA & Temp \\
        \midrule
        English & The sun is shining brightly today & The sun is shining brightly today & {\ipafont ðə sʌn ɪz ˈʃaɪnɪŋ ˈbraɪtˡli təˈdeɪ} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Mandarin Chinese & \textchinese{今天太阳很亮} & Jīntiān tàiyáng yǎrqdiào zhàoyàozhe & {\ipafont jɪnˈtʰien tai̯ˈjaŋ jǎːrqdiàu ʈʂao̯jao̯ʈʂɤ} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Spanish & \textspanish{Hoy el sol brilla intensamente hoy} & Hoy el sol brilla intensamente hoy & {\ipafont oi el ˈsol ˈbrilla inˈtensaˈmente oi} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Arabic & \textarabic{االيوم الشمس تشرق الزاهية} & Al-yom ash-shams tashraqo az-zāhiyah & {\ipafont alˈjoːm ʔaʃˈʃams taʃraqʊ ʔazˈzaːhijah} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Portuguese & \textportuguese{Hoje o sol está brilhando intensamente hoje} & Hoje o sol está brilhando intensamente hoje & {\ipafont ˈoʒi o ˈsɔw ˈesta brilˈjandu inˈtẽˈsamente ˈoʒi} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        French & \textfrench{Aujourd'hui, le soleil brille intensément aujourd'hui} & Aujourd'hui, le soleil brille intensément aujourd'hui & {\ipafont oʒuʁˈdui lə soˈlɛj bril intensəmɑ̃ oʒuʁˈdui} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Japanese  & \textjapanese{今日、太陽は今\-日はとても明る\-く輝いています} & Kyōjitsu, taiyō wa kyō wa totemo akiraka ni hikatte imasu & {\ipafont kʲoːdzit͡su taijoː wa kʲoː wa totemo akaraka ni hikatte imasu} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Tamil & \texttamil{இன்று சூரியன் மிகவும் பிரகாசமாக பிரகாசிக்கிறது} & Indru sūriyan mikavum pirakāśamakāga pirakāśikkiradu & {\ipafont indu suːrijan mikavum piɾakaːsamaːgaka piɾakaːsikkiɾadu} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        German & \textgerman{Heute scheint die Sonne heute sehr hell} & Heute scheint die Sonne heute sehr hell & {\ipafont ˈhɔʏtə ˈʃaɪnt diː ˈzɔnə ˈhɔʏtə zeːr ˈhɛl} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Hindi & \texthindi{आज सूर्य बहुत चमक रहा है आज} & Aaj sūrya bahut chamak rahā hai aaj & {\ipafont aːdz suːrya bahut ˈt͡ʃəmək ˈraɦa hɛː aːdz} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Bengali  & \textbengali{আজ সূর্য খুব ঝলমলে আছে আজ} & Aaj shurjo khub jholungmole ache aaj & {\ipafont aːdz ʃurjo khub ˈd͡ʒʱolomole at͡ʃe aaj} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Russian & \textrussian{Сегодня солнце ярко светит сегодня} & Segodnya solntse yarko svetit segodnya & {\ipafont sʲɪˈvodnʲə ˈsolnt͡sə ˈjarko ˈsʲvʲetit sʲɪˈvodnʲə} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Thank you @cfr please consider this when developing Latex3

@heavendew You're welcome, but I assure you I have nothing to do with developing LaTeX3! You'd need to speak to one of the development team. Some of them are on this site, but they would not let me near LaTeX3 with a barge pole (and rightly so).

With LuaLateX one can leverage the fallback mechanism to sort of join fonts. This avoids having to continuously having to type \text... etc.
The fallback mechanism will substitute glyphs, from the fallback fonts table if the current font does not have it. I have used Brill as the main font, as it has good support for accents. Substitute with your favourite. I added some cuneiform at the end of the table to highlight the advantages.
The fallback mechanism will not load patterns, replace sectioning strings and does not work well with RTL scripts. I left polyglossia for these, although with etex, one can define suitable short commands for these. It also does not apply any typographical conventions. See https://www.w3.org/TR/jlreq/?lang=en://www.w3.org/International/articles/typography/justification

Here is some code. You will need mostly Noto fonts, if you uncomment the lua by removing the (--) in front of some of the fonts, you can type any of the current Unicode 15.0 scripts.
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{panunicode.lua}
panunicode=panunicode or {}
local mycolor="FF0000"
panunicode={
  --"Aegean.ttf:mode=harf;FF0000;",
  -- "NotoSansPahawhHmong:mode=harf;color="..mycolor..";",
  -- "NotoSansInscriptionalPahlavi-Regular:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
  --  "NotoSansBrahmi:harf=node;color=FF0000;",
  --  "NotoSansGlagolitic:harf=node;color=FF0000;",
  --  "NotoSansSiddham:harf=node;color=FF0000;",
  --  "NotoSansBatak:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
  --  "NotoSansBuhid:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
  --  "NotoSansBuginese:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
  --  "NotoSansHanunoo-Regular:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
  --  "NotoSansTagbanwa-Regular:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
  --  "NotoSans Rejang-Regular:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
  --  "NotoSansArmenian:mode=node;color=0000FF;",
  --  "NotoSansGeorgian-Regular:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
  --  "Mingzat-R.ttf:mode=harf;color=FF0000;", --slow triggers
  -- "NotoSansTagalog:mode=node;color=FF000000;",
  -- "NotoSerifNPHmong:mode=harf;color=FF000000;",
  --  "NotoSansNushu:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
  --  "Estrangelo Edessa:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
   --  "MenaionUnicode.otf:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
  --   "NotoSansSymbols2-Regular:mode=node;color=FF000000;",
  -- "Symbola:mode=harf;color=FF0000",
 --  "NotoSansNko:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansAdlam:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  " NotoSansSumeroAkkadianCuneiform:mode=node;color=0000FF;",
 --  "NotoSansMarchen:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --   "NotoSerifMakasar:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "AksaraBali:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansEthiopic:mode=harf;color=0000FF;",
 --  "NotoSansSoyombo:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansGrantha:mode=harf;color=0000FF;",
 --   "NotoSansBassaVah:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansDeseret:mode=harf;",
 --  "NotoSansOldHungarian:mode=harf;",
 --  "NotoSansMeeteiMayek:mode=harf;",
 --  "NotoSansGurmukhi:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansOldTurkic:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansChakma:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansTelugu:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansSundanese:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansOsage:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansLao:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansCaucasianAlbanian:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansTaiViet:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSerifTangut:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansTifinagh:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansTagbanwa:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansTakri:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansOlChiki:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansLimbu:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansKhmer:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansCham:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
 --  "NotoSansJavanese:mode=harf;color=0000FF;",
 --  "NotoSansSaurashtra:mode=harf;color=0000FF;",
     "NotoSansTamil:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansSamaritan:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansBengali:mode=harf;script=bng2;color=0000FF;",
   "NotoSansMyanmar:mode=harf;script=auto;color=0000FF;",
   "NotoSansBamum:mode=harf;color=0000FF;",
   "NotoSansDeseret:mode=harf;script=deseret;",
   "NotoSansMandaic-Regular:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansOldSouthArabian:mode=harf;",
   "NotoSansOldNorthArabian:mode=harf;",
   "NotoSansImperialAramaic:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansPalmyrene:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansHatran:mode=harf;color=0000FF;",
   "NotoSansOldItalic:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansOgham:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansLepcha:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSerifTibetan:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansOldPersian:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansRunic:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansCherokee:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansCanadianAboriginal:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSansGothic:mode=harf;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSerifYezidi:mode=harf;color=00FF00;",
   "NotoSansYi:mode=harf;color=100000;",
   "NotoSansKawi:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
    "NotoSansDevanagari:mode=harf;color=0000FF;",
    "NotoSansMyanmar:mode=node;color=FF0000;",
   "NotoSerifCJK-Regular.ttc:mode=harf;color=0000FF;",
  -- "LastResort:mode=node;color=100010;",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{panunicode.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage{panunicode}{2024/05/02}{versionv1.0}{Combine fonts into  panunicode (YL)}
    \RequirePackage{luacode}

     \directlua{require("panunicode")
     luaotfload.add_fallback("panunicode",panunicode)}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

%\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{arabic, tamil, hindi}

%\newfontfamily\chinesefont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
%\newfontfamily\spanishfont{Liberation Serif}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}
%\newfontfamily\portuguesefont{DejaVu Sans}
%\newfontfamily\frenchfont{DejaVu Sans}
%\newfontfamily\japanesefont{Noto Sans CJK JP}
\newfontfamily\tamilfont{Noto Sans Tamil}
%\newfontfamily\germanfont{DejaVu Serif}
%\newfontfamily\hindifont{Noto Sans Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Noto Sans Bengali}
%\newfontfamily\russianfont{PT Sans}
%\newfontfamily{Charis SIL}

\usepackage{panunicode}
\setmainfont{Brill}[%FreeSerif or code2000
   Scale             = 1.07,
   Ligatures         = {Common,NoRare},%
   SmallCapsFeatures = {RawFeature=+c2sc},%
   Renderer          = Node,%
   Numbers           = Lining,%
   RawFeature={fallback=panunicode},
]

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Examples of Transliteration from different languages to UniGlyph:}
    \label{tab:transliteration}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{RRRRR}
        \toprule
        Language & Script in native language & English equivalent & IPA & Temp \\
        \midrule
        English & The sun is shining brightly today & The sun is shining brightly today & { ðə sʌn ɪz ˈʃaɪnɪŋ ˈbraɪtˡli təˈdeɪ} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Mandarin Chinese & {今天太阳很亮} & Jīntiān tàiyáng yǎrqdiào zhàoyàozhe & { jɪnˈtʰien tai̯ˈjaŋ jǎːrqdiàu ʈʂao̯jao̯ʈʂɤ} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Spanish & {Hoy el sol brilla intensamente hoy} & Hoy el sol brilla intensamente hoy & { oi el ˈsol ˈbrilla inˈtensaˈmente oi} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Arabic & \textarabic{االيوم الشمس تشرق الزاهية} & Al-yom ash-shams tashraqo az-zāhiyah & { alˈjoːm ʔaʃˈʃams taʃraqʊ ʔazˈzaːhijah} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Portuguese & Hoje o sol está brilhando intensamente hoje & Hoje o sol está brilhando intensamente hoje & ˈoʒi o ˈsɔw ˈesta brilˈjandu inˈtẽˈsamente ˈoʒi & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
%        French & \textfrench{Aujourd'hui, le soleil brille intensément aujourd'hui} & Aujourd'hui, le soleil brille intensément aujourd'hui & { oʒuʁˈdui lə soˈlɛj bril intensəmɑ̃ oʒuʁˈdui} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
  Japanese  & 今日、太陽は今\-日はとても明る\-く輝いています & Kyōjitsu, taiyō wa kyō wa totemo akiraka ni hikatte imasu &  kʲoːdzit͡su taijoː wa kʲoː wa totemo akaraka ni hikatte imasu & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Tamil & இன்று சூரியன் மிகவும் பிரகாசமாக பிரகாசிக்கிறது & Indru sūriyan mikavum pirakāśamakāga pirakāśikkiradu &  indu suːrijan mikavum piɾakaːsamaːgaka piɾakaːsikkiɾadu & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        German & Heute scheint die Sonne heute sehr hell & Heute scheint die Sonne heute sehr hell &  ˈhɔʏtə ˈʃaɪnt diː ˈzɔnə ˈhɔʏtə zeːr ˈhɛl & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Hindi &  आज सूर्य बहुत चमक रहा है आज & Aaj sūrya bahut chamak rahā hai aaj & { aːdz suːrya bahut ˈt͡ʃəmək ˈraɦa hɛː aːdz} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Bengali  & আজ সূর্য খুব ঝলমলে আছে আজ & Aaj shurjo khub jholungmole ache aaj & { aːdz ʃurjo khub ˈd͡ʒʱolomole at͡ʃe aaj} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Russian & Сегодня солнце ярко светит сегодня & Segodnya solntse yarko svetit segodnya & { sʲɪˈvodnʲə ˈsolnt͡sə ˈjarko ˈsʲvʲetit sʲɪˈvodnʲə} & dn OaS eFO vaeSeA bsaeNle NuReG \\
        Old Persian &   /& &\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Ah, fallback fonts ;).

Thank you @yannisl please consider this when developing Latex3. BTW thank you for adding Old Persian
