Creating a Multi-page, Auto-scaling Table with Repeating Headers in LaTeX for Multilingual Data
I need assistance in creating a LaTeX table in overleaf that can span multiple pages, automatically scale its columns to fit content when additional columns are added, and include repeating headers on each page. The table will contain transliterations of a sentence across multiple languages, along with their IPA transliterations.
    \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Transliteration from different languages:}
  \label{tab:transliteration}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{RRRR}
    \toprule
    Language & Script in native language & English equivalent & IPA \\
    \midrule
    English & The sun is shining brightly today & The sun is shining brightly today & {\ipafont ðə sʌn ɪz ˈʃaɪnɪŋ ˈbraɪtˡli təˈdeɪ} \\
    Mandarin Chinese & \textchinese{今天的阳光明媚} & Jīntiān de yángguāng míngmèi & {\ipafont t͡ɕɪn˥ tʰjɛn˥ jaŋ˥ kwaŋ˥ miŋ˧ meɪ˧˥} \\
    Spanish & \textspanish{Hoy el sol brilla intensamente hoy} & Hoy el sol brilla intensamente hoy & {\ipafont oi el ˈsol ˈbrilla inˈtensaˈmente oi} \\
    Arabic & \textarabic{االيوم الشمس تشرق الزاهية} & Al-yom ash-shams tashraqo az-zāhiyah & {\ipafont alˈjoːm ʔaʃˈʃams taʃraqʊ ʔazˈzaːhijah} \\
    Portuguese & \textportuguese{Hoje o sol está brilhando intensamente hoje} & Hoje o sol está brilhando intensamente hoje & {\ipafont ˈoʒi o ˈsɔw ˈesta brilˈjandu inˈtẽˈsamente ˈoʒi} \\
    French & \textfrench{Aujourd'hui, le soleil brille intensément aujourd'hui} & Aujourd'hui, le soleil brille intensément aujourd'hui & {\ipafont oʒuʁˈdui lə soˈlɛj bril intensəmɑ̃ oʒuʁˈdui} \\
    Japanese & \textjapanese{今日、太陽は今 日はとても明る く輝いています} & Kyōjitsu, taiyō wa kyō wa totemo akiraka ni hikatte imasu & {\ipafont kʲoːdzit͡su taijoː wa kʲoː wa totemo akaraka ni hikatte imasu} \\
    Tamil & \texttamil{இன்று சூரியன் மிகவும் பிரகாசமாக பிரகாசிக்கிறது} & Indru sūriyan mikavum pirakāśamakāga pirakāśikkiradu & {\ipafont indu suːrijan mikavum piɾakaːsamaːgaka piɾakaːsikkiɾadu} \\
    German & \textgerman{Heute scheint die Sonne heute sehr hell} & Heute scheint die Sonne heute sehr hell & {\ipafont ˈhɔʏtə ˈʃaɪnt diː ˈzɔnə ˈhɔʏtə zeːr ˈhɛl} \\
    Hindi & \texthindi{आज सूरज बहुत चमक रहा है आज} & Aaj sooraj bahut chamak rahā hai aaj & {\ipafont aːdz suːrya bahut t͡ʃəmək raɦa hɛː aːdz} \\
    Bengali & \textbengali{সূর্য আজ খুব উজ্জ্বল} & Sūrya āja khuba ujjbala & {\ipafont ˈsuːɾjɔ ˈaːdʒ ˈkhub ˈuddʒɔl} \\
    Russian & \textrussian{Сегодня сегодня ярко светит солнце} & Segodnya segodnya yarko svetit solntse & {\ipafont sʲevɐˈdɲa sʲevɐˈdɲa ˈjarka ˈsviertʲit ˈsolnt͡sɨ} \\
    Hebrew & \hebrewfont{השמש זורחת בבהירות היום} & HaShamesh zoret be'behirut hayom & {\ipafont haʃaˈmeʃ zoˈret bevihiˈrut haˈjom} \\
    Greek & \greekfont{ἥλιος λάμπει φωτεινῶς σήμερον} & Hhēlios lampei phōteinōs sēmeron & {\ipafont ˈheːlios ˈlampi fotiˈnos ˈseːmeron} \\
    Latin & \latinfont{Sol splendet clare hodie} & Sol splendēt clārē hodiē & {\ipafont sɔl ˈsplɛndɛt ˈklare ˈhodie} \\
    Old Persian & \oldpersianfont{  } & Huvašra citiya hya haruva duvarš tiy & {\ipafont huvaʃra citija hja haruva duvarʃ tiy} \\
    Dutch & \textdutch{Vandaag schijnt de zon fel vandaag} & Vandaag schijnt de zon fel vandaag & {\ipafont vɑnˈdaːx ˈsxɛint də ˈzɔn fɛl vɑnˈdaːx} \\
    Korean & \textkorean{오늘 태양이 밝게 빛난다 오늘} & Oneul taeyang-i balkge bichnanda oneul & {\ipafont onɯl tʰɛjaŋi palkːe pit͡ɕnanda onɯl} \\
    Swedish & \textswedish{Idag skiner solen klart idag} & Idag skiner solen klart idag & {\ipafont ɪˈdɑː ˈʃiːnər ˈsuːlɛn ˈklɑːʈ ɪˈdɑː} \\
    Ancient Egyptian & \textegyptian{} & Ra hrw šsp m dšr.w ḥr ibd & {\ipafont ra ħrw ʃsp m dʃrw ħr ibd} \\
    Aramaic & \textaramaic{ܫܡܫܐ ܕܫܡܫܐ ܠܩܕܫܐ ܝܘܡܐ} & Shəmshā dshəmshā l'qādshā yawmā & {\ipafont ʃəmʃa dəʃəmʃa lqaːdʃa jɑwmaː} \\
    Italian & \textitalian{Oggi il sole splende luminosamente oggi} & Oggi il sole splende luminosamente oggi & {\ipafont ˈɔddʒi il ˈsole ˈsplɛnde luˈminozamente ˈɔddʒi} \\
    Sumerian & \textsumerian{} & Utu-da ud-lu-un-na-da-lil₂-ḫa & {\ipafont utu da ud luna da lil ħa} \\
    Akkadian & \textakkadian{} & Šamaš ērib issak marduk zi' gub ma & {\ipafont ʃamaʃ eːrib issak marːduːk ziː guːb ma} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


please fix your example so people can run it and see the issue, you are using 4 (undefined) R columns but only have three columns of data, several package provide combinations of longtable and tabularx see for example xltabular  or alternatives such as tabularray also provide that functionality

Thank you for pointing out the issue. I apologize for the confusion in my example code. I've updated the code snippet to correctly use 4 columns of data. Could you please help adapt this to a more modern LaTeX3 table package since you are working on it

I have some table packages but I wouldn't call them modern, most of them have not had changed code since last century

Scaling tabulars is discouraged.  You could adjust the font size instead.
