Compiling multi-script unicode LaTeX documents
I'm trying to write a latex document that supports arbitrary utf-8 encoded scripts. This is turning out to be surprisingly difficult. A key point is that I want to get this working without specifying fonts or scripts within the content, I want to rely on fonts that implement most of the unicode glyphs, and then simply write text that may contain various characters. Sort of how everything else works, from the terminal via browsers and editors to compilers and interpreters.
I've been experimenting a bit with xelatex and lualatex, but I've not had great luck so far. I have a sort of minimal sample that looks like this:
\documentclass{article}

% Ensure UTF-8 encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Font package for handling a wide range of Unicode characters
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Set main font (choose a font with good Unicode support)
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\begin{document}

This document includes various Unicode characters:

* Latin (English): Hello, world!  This is a test.  
* Cyrillic (Russian): привет мир!  Это тест.  
* Arabic (Egyptian): مرحبا بالعالم! هذا اختبار. 
* Chinese (Simplified): 你好世界！这是一个测试。
* Japanese (Hiragana): こんにちは世界！これはテストです。

\end{document}

But I'm struggling to get that working with all the included text showing in the resulting pdf.
I found a sample on https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/luatex/generic/luaotfload/scripts-demo.tex and after massaging it I had some success with lualatex, though I'm struggling to extend it with more scripts. So the following appears to work when I define all these different fallbacks, but I'm surprised at all the work required to get international text working, and I'm wondering if I'm headed down a wrong path.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Define fonts and fallbacks in Lua
\directlua{
  % Define fonts with modes and scripts
  local fonts = {
    burmesefont = "NotoSerifMyanmar-Regular.ttf:mode=harf;script=mym2;",
    devafont = "NotoSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf:mode=harf;script=dev2;",
    banglafont = "NotoSansBengali-Regular.ttf:mode=harf;script=bng2;",
    tibetanfont = "NotoSerifTibetan-Regular.ttf:mode=harf;script=tibt;",
  }
  
  % Add fallbacks in order of preference
  luaotfload.add_fallback("myfallback", {
    fonts.burmesefont,
    fonts.devafont,
    fonts.banglafont,
    fonts.tibetanfont,
    "Noto Sans:mode=node;"
  })
}

% Set main font with fallback using RawFeature
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}[
  Renderer=HarfBuzz,
  RawFeature={fallback=myfallback}
]

\begin{document}

မ္မတီခေါင်းလောင်းကြီ\\
क्रर्कि \\
কণ্যা এখন কি করিবে\\
སྐྱེས་ཙམ་ཉིད་ནས་ཆེ་མཐོངས་དང༌།

\end{document}

Is there some sort of catch-all solution in latex that works with most scripts?

the fallback code you found is more or less what you have to do. Side remark: You can delete \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}. luatex will ignore it anyway and with pdflatex it is the default.

This will work as advertised but you will still need to use Babel for all the right to left scripts, like Arabic or Hebrew etc. I have similar code for all the unicode ranges.

See my answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/718114/japanese-font-in-table-overlaps-with-adjacent-column-when-compiled-with-xelatex/718211#718211

Do note that you will not get proper hyphenation if you do not change the language settings between scripts.
